# Can significance check be applied and which one?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Collective wisdom is desperately needed! I need to understand if some kind of significance testing is applicable here, and if that is the case - which test.

The data collection was devised as follows:
There are 3 stations where people perform a number of station-specific manual tasks.

On each of three test days different people were assigned to stations (9 people in total). people were of different height, age and weight.

Each person (at each station on each day) was subjected to 5000 measurements of his kinetic activity, later classified as "good" or "bad".
The percentages of "good" and "bad" for each person (and day and station) are thus known.

3 people from day one are treated as a "control group", or baseline.

I would like to know if a significance test is possible for percentages @ station[x] and day one (and baseline person working at that station on day one) and percentages @ same station for a different day/person.

say station 1 was a "drill and rotate".
On day one, John worked there alone and had 80% good drill-and-rotate movements and 20% bad ones (out of 5000 measured)
On day two, Jill worked there, had ongoing egonomic instructions and had 85% and 15% respectively.

Null hypothesis is (I am guessing) "the difference can be attributed to natural variation in humans only"
I want to test the significance of "had ergonomic instructions".

Can it be done with such a setup and which formula?
Or is it a faulty experiment design and such testing is impossible?

Please help. I am no statistician and I am at my wits' end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is output from Minitab 17 based on the model in my previous answer.
Data were entered as percents, just as you provided them.

P-values for Day and Station effects are both above 5%. This indicates
that no significant differences were found among Days or among Stations.

Differences between %-Good scores for individuals fluctuate so much, apparently
at random, that it is not possible to discern systematic differences among
Days or Stations above that 'noise'.

```
ANOVA: Good versus Day, Station 

Factor   Type   Levels  Values
Day      fixed       3  1, 2, 3
Station  fixed       3  1, 2, 3


Analysis of Variance for Good

Source   DF        SS        MS     F      P
Day       2  0.036492  0.018246  1.93  0.260
Station   2  0.008025  0.004012  0.42  0.681
Error     4  0.037910  0.009478
Total     8  0.082427


S = 0.0973528   R-Sq = 54.01%   R-Sq(adj) = 8.02%
```

A normal plot of the residuals from the model shows that the nine
residuals fall very nearly in a straight line. That is, residuals
are consistent with normality.

[image]

So that you can check the data I used, here is a table. Margins
are row and column averages.

```
Rows: Day   Columns: Station

            1       2       3     All

1      0.7403  0.4583  0.6582  0.6189
            1       1       1       3

2      0.7483  0.8024  0.7255  0.7587
            1       1       1       3

3      0.7544  0.7645  0.7273  0.7487
            1       1       1       3

All    0.7477  0.6751  0.7037  0.7088
            3       3       3       9

Cell Contents:  Good  :  Mean
                         Count
```

*Note:* Individual 95% confidence intervals for your percentages (based on 5000
trials each) are about $\pm$1.5%. There are ${9 \choose 2} = 36$ pairs
of individuals. I certainly don't encourage you to check all pairs for
significant differences, because by chance alone you would likely find several 'significant'
differences that way. However, if there is  a *one* specific pair of subjects
that was of particular interest (before you saw data), you might look at that one.

For example, if the difference between John and Jill (mentioned individually in your Question)  is of particular importance, then we can test to find that they gave
significantly different proportions of Good responses (P-value very small):

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

 Sample     X     N  Sample p
 1       4000  5000  0.800000
 2       4250  5000  0.850000

 Difference = p (1) - p (2)
 Estimate for difference:  -0.05
 95% CI for difference:  (-0.0648622, -0.0351378)
 Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -6.59  P-Value = 0.000
```

BTW: I don't find John and Jill in the data you provided most recently.

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly enough information for a definitive answer:

**Days.** Are there designed differences among the three Days (that carry across stations)? [You hint that John (Day 1) was somehow treated differently than Jill (Day 2). What about Day 3?]

**Stations.** Are there designed differences among the three Stations (that carry across days)? [You hint that this may be so. Station 1 is 'drill and rotate'. What about Stations 2 and 3?] ]

**Tentative model.** From what (little) I can gather from your description, I *guess* that this may be a two-factor ANOVA (3 Stations $\times$ 3 Days.) with one observation per 'cell'. The model might be
$$Y_{ij} + \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j + e_{ij},$$
for $i = 1,2,3$ days and $j = 1,2,3$ stations, where independently $e_{ij} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0, \sigma).$

The ANOVA table would have three rows:  Days, Stations, Error.
Because there is only one observation per cell, there would be no interaction term.

**Data.**  Data would be fractions Good out of  5000. Although technically binomial proportions, i guess my first try at analysis would be to treat
data as normal (as presaged by the tentative model) because the number of trials per subject is so large. I would certainly want
to check whether the nine residuals seem consistent with normal.

**Contrast.** It seems that Day 1 ('treated as a control') might be treated
differently from Days 2 and 3. If that is so, and the Day-effect is
significant, you might want to test whether the *designed* contrast (comparing Day 1 against the other two),
based on the coefficient vector $c=(1, -.5, -.5)$ is significant.

**Design flaws.** Without seeing the data or understanding the nature of
the effects under study, I'm guessing that it would have been better to
have five times as many subjects, each doing 1000 trials. Unless effects
are profoundly large or variability much smaller than is usual using
human subjects. I suppose that one subject in each of the $3 \times 3$ cells
will not provide enough power to find significant differences. (Even twice
as many subjects, 2500 trials, 2 observations per cell would have been a lot better.)

Are any apparent differences among subjects due to personal differences, or
are they due to different performances of the same subject across time?
With this design we'll never know. Did anyone stop to think that three
randomly chosen subjects are hardly enough for a 'baseline' of any kind?

The time to think about analyzing data from a study is ***before*** the
study is done. It is regrettable if so much effort has been expended
with no clear model or strategy for analysis in mind.

Comment: to address your question: day 1 - John works @ station 1 with no instructions;  day 2 - Jill works  @station 1, is given instructions; day 3 - Jorge works @ station 1, is given visual aid. Stations (and corresponding actions people do @ them) are different. However, similar movements, like raising arms and rotationg elbows are measured @ each station.

Comment: also, entirely different set of people (Charles, Cassie, Cindy) worked station 2 and (Lenny, Lorna, Lou) worked station 3. The design is indeed terribly bad and not nearly enogh people participated. I was howerver just given the data to analyse and had no power to influence the experiment.

Comment: Could you show me the formula and possible conclusions from "2-factor ANOVA"? as I said, I have no background in statistics, and parts of your answer are just confusing :)

Comment: As I understand it, you have nine numbers (such as John's .80 and Jill's .95. Can you put them into a $3 \times 3$ table in your question. Then I can try the ANOVA. // At some point you will probably have to look at a statistics book, having 'no background in statistics' is not necessarily a permanent condition.

Comment: as comments section doesn't allow for linebreaks I have put my numbers as an "answer" to my own question here. Seems it appears above the thread and not below it. @BruceET

Comment: Best to edit data into your Question.

Answer (score 0):

```
stations    day1        day2        day3
1           74.03%      74.83%      75.44%
2           45.83%      80.24%      76.45%
3           65.82%      72.55%      72.73%
```

percentages are proportions of "good"  movements @ corresponding day and station.
people working stations on day 1 weren't assisted by anything,
people working stations on day 2 were given instructions,
people working on day 3 were given visual aids.

Question: did the "ergonomic interference" influence proportion of "good" movements?